# Web applications for annotating webpages for free?

Tags: gratis, web-apps, note-taking

Are there Web applications for annotating webpages for free?

I would like to underline, highlight, and add notes to a webpage I am browsing in my browser (Firefox).

Whether the annotations can be saved or not are both fine, although being saved is better.

I am using [Diigo](https://www.diigo.com/), but it only offers 1000 highlights per year for free.

Comment: Do you want annotations to be stored online or offline?

Comment: I would like to know both online and offline. I hope it will not consume too much CPU and RAM of my laptop.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing! Thank you for your question. I want also a replacement for Diigo, way too expensive. The Diigo caching page, the highlighting and annotation tool seems hard to imitate it seems.

Comment: And hosting your own content, are you interested in this possibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can recommend two:

#### Awesome Screenshot Plus

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/awesome-screenshot-capture-/

It's essentially a screenshot app that allows you to annotate those screenshots, draw on them and then save those.

#### Scribble

http://www.scrible.com/

Highlight, color, bold, underline, italicize and strikethrough text to flag critical passages and parts of a web page. Also allows you too save pages.

Comment: Does scribble save annotated webpages on my computer or their online server?

Comment: I think it's online only. At least it doesn't say on the site that offline saving is supported, but it could be a feature.

Comment: [Awesome Screenshot Plus for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-captur/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce/related)

Comment: Awesome screenshot, yes, but after that, how to make on offline site with that?