# Seeking a tool for tagging & annotating online content

Tags: web, research

I'm looking for an online research tool that will allow me to annotate & tag material I read online, and connect it to other material. The situation I'm imagining is something like this:

1. Read online article; find interesting/important information.
2. Remember important connection to an article I read six months ago, potentially useful in current or future project.
3. Find article from six months ago by searching tags.
4. Apply same tag to new article, plus a specific reference to the older article.
5. Annotate new article with relevant thought/observation/question/comment.

I originally imagined this as some sort of web-based overlay (e.g., a browser plugin), but I'd be open to downloaded software as well. Gratis is nice, but I'm willing to pay for the right tool. Cross-platform is important.

As for what's already out there: Pocket has tags, but not annotation; ditto Google Keep; DevonThink, which apparently still exists, feels like overkill; I did use Evernote a long time ago, but found it clunky and not really helpful. (If it's improved enough that I should try going back, I'm open to that.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web applications for annotating webpages for free](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2959/web-applications-for-annotating-webpages-for-free)? If not, please clarify how your requirements are different. Also, I reviewed a few options in [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/52383/add-help-tips-for-my-coworkers-to-3rd-party-web-apps) that didn't meet my requirements, but they might meet yours.

Answer (score 1):

I use a [TiddlyWiki](https://tiddlywiki.com/) for a similar purpose. However, this is more of a Wiki-system that requires you to create your own Wiki-page (tiddler) for each annotation, whereby the link to the website you address should be added manually.

Other than that, could [Hypothes.is](https://web.hypothes.is/) be something for you?

To cite its "See how it works"-section:

> **Select text to annotate**.
> Add tags and post publicly or save privately.
>
> **Reply to or share any annotation**.
> Link to notes or whole pages.
>
> **Annotate together in groups**.
> Collaborate privately with others.
>
> **Search your notes**.
> Explore all public annotations and profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Memex at getmemex.com is foss, can record your searches and sites visited, can search text of recordings and allows annotation on sites. Can tag and search for tags. It is supposed to work on chrome and firefox so if you can install them memex should work as well.

Comment: Does it allow tag search? Please describe how. Also, is it cross-platform? Please read https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality/387#387 and edit your answer.